# I have a pop up menu for a calculator app. When I select the calculator, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? All three calculators are stateful

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the main page where the basic calculator is set up as the home page:

```
class BasicCalculator extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      //defines home page
      theme: ThemeData(),
      initialRoute: '/basic',
      routes: {
        '/basic': (context) => BasicScreen(),
        '/prime': (context) => PrimeFactorScreen(),
        '/scientific': (context) => ScientificScreen(),
      },
      //home: BasicScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the menu. This is set up to be a button on the calculator which brings up the menu. The menu shows up just as it's supposed to, but the routing doesn't work:

```
Widget buildMenuButton(buttonMargin, String buttonClass, String buttonText, textStyle, buttonDecoration) {
    return Container(
      margin: buttonMargin,
      child: PopupMenuButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
        //color: Colors.cyan,
        //elevation: 60,
        onSelected: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _value = value as String;
          });
        },
        itemBuilder: (context) => [
          PopupMenuItem(
            child: Text("Prime Factor"),
            //value: "prime",
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/prime');
            },
          ),
          PopupMenuItem(
            child: Text("Basic"),
            //value: "basic",
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/basic');
            },
          ),
          PopupMenuItem(
            child: Text("Scientific"),
            value: "scientific",
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/scientific');
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      decoration: buttonDecoration,
    );
 }
```

Comment: Do you have any logs?

Comment: If this is what you mean, I get this when I put print directly under the child in each menu choice:                                                                                                        I/flutter (10734): PopupMenuButton<dynamic>(dependencies: [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#05f88], _InheritedTheme], state: PopupMenuButtonState<dynamic>#5658f)

Comment: I used print(context).